# Сравнить java-код по функциональности

Tags: java, функции

По заданию нужно было сделать код как на картинке, но я, собрал вот такой, и хотел бы узнать, одинаковы ли они по функциональности и в чём плюсы или минусы моего варианта программы?
Вот текст задания:

> Define a function called monopolyRoll(). This function provides a
>   random result based on the dice-rolling rules for the board game
>   Monopoly. In Monopoly, players roll two six-sided dice to determine
>   their move. If they roll the same value on both dice, this is called
>   “rolling doubles,” and it means they go again. In our simplified
>   version, the dice-roll function should behave like this:
>
> 1. Generate two random integers in the 1 to 6 range.
> 2. If the numbers are not the same, return the sum.
> 3. If the numbers are the same, generate two more random integers in the 1 to 6 range, and return the sum of all 4 numbers.
>
> Hint: to make
>   your code neater, you can define a second function that generates a
>   random integer in the 1 to 6 range (or in the 1 to x range based on a
>   parameter) so that you do not need to keep repeating that code.

[image: "правильный" вариант программы]

```
public class Main {

    public static int monopolyRoll() {
       double randomNumber1 = Math.random();
       randomNumber1 = randomNumber1 * 6;
       randomNumber1 = randomNumber1 + 1;
       int randomInt1 = (int)randomNumber1;

       double randomNumber2 = Math.random();
       randomNumber2 = randomNumber2 * 6;
       randomNumber2 = randomNumber2 + 1;
       int randomInt2 = (int)randomNumber2;

       if (randomInt1 != randomInt2){
           int randomNumSum = randomInt1 + randomInt2;
           return randomNumSum;
       }
       else {
           double randomNumber3 = Math.random();
           randomNumber3 = randomNumber3 * 6;
           randomNumber3 = randomNumber3 + 1;
           int randomInt3 = (int)randomNumber3;

           double randomNumber4 = Math.random();
           randomNumber4 = randomNumber4 * 6;
           randomNumber4 = randomNumber4 + 1;
           int randomInt4 = (int)randomNumber4;

           int rollingDoublesSum = randomInt1 + randomInt2 + randomInt3 + randomInt4;

           System.out.println("It's a rolling doubles!");
           return rollingDoublesSum;
       }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(monopolyRoll());

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) За название переменных `randomNumber1, randomNumber2, randomNumber<n>` нужно по рукам бить :) 2) за копипастные куски кода `randomNumber1 = randomNumber1 * 6;` и им подобные тоже. По функциональности оба кода, я думаю, одинаковые, но первый с `diceRoll` выглядит проще

Comment: За 1 и 2 прошу понять и простить, я только учусь ^^'
А так, спасибо!